# Why is my NUnit test failing?

Tags: c#, unit-testing, visual-studio-2013, nunit, integration-testing

I added an NUNit test (NUnit newby here):

```
[Test]
public void TestHHSDeliveryInterface()
{
    var Delivery = IOC.container.Resolve<IHHSDelivery>();

    var i = Delivery.GetCount();

    Assert.Greater(i, 16);
}
```

...based on an existing one that works:

```
[Test]
public void TestHHSInterface()
{
    var HHSClient = IOC.container.Resolve<IHHSClient>();

    var s = HHSClient.GetTestMessage("Dom", "Paz");

    Assert.Greater(s.Value.Length, 0);
}
```

...for some context, the class starts this way:

```
[TestFixture, Category(SSCSCOMMON.UnitTests.Categories.IntegrationTest)]
public class HHSClientIntegrationTests
{
```

The method (Delivery.GetCount();) is returning a "canned" value (17) for now. So it itself works. So why is the test failing? Unfortunately, the test code is not breakpointable - at least, I have a breakpoint in it, and it doesn't ever get reached, which it should if it's failing, I would think, normally. NUnit looks like this after I run the app and the tests:

[image]

With the problematic test commented out, the others run fine.

### UPDATE

It turns out that solving [this problem](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24375991/how-can-i-add-a-dependency-that-can-be-used-as-type-parameter-timpl-for-castle) also solved this one.

Comment: It's hard to tell without the code lines in your example.  But the error message is saying that the failure is on line 59 of `RESTHHSDelivery.cs`  Are you sure you are getting back the correct `IHHSDelivery` instance from `IOC.container.Resolve<IHHSDelivery>()` in your test?

Comment: Can you show the `RESTHHSDelivery.cs` code?  It would seem that something in there is throwing a `System.NotImplementedException`.  This is often the case when you create classes and methods using IDE tools.  Check your constructors, and the implementation for `GetCount()`

Comment: It turns out that solving [this problem][1] also solved this one.


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24375991/how-can-i-add-a-dependency-that-can-be-used-as-type-parameter-timpl-for-castle

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using my psychic debug skills:

> So why is the test failing? Unfortunately, the test code is not
>   breakpointable - at least, I have a breakpoint in it, and it doesn't
>   ever get reached, which it should if it's failing, I would think,
>   normally.

You are not running the unit test on the dll you think you are debugging. I guess your debug breakpoint tells you the code you are running differs form the source code. Clean your deployment directories/ and your project (all dlls) and recompile.